# Class-based view mess about overwriting generic view methods

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I try get this to work:

```
url(r'^index$', Index.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^index/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', Index.as_view(), name='index'),
```

I have

```
class Index(MyView):
```

derived from

```
class MyViewBase(TemplateView, DetectMobileMixin, TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin):
```

by default it is rendering template but i made mixin for `Index`

```
class jsonMixin(object):
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'pk' in kwargs:
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            pk = kwargs['pk']
            data = self.data_json(pk)
            json_data = json.dumps(data)
            return HttpResponse(json_data,content_type='application/json')
        else:
            self.context["pokaz_element"] = self.id
    return super().get(*args, **kwargs)

class Index(MyViewBase,  jsonMixin):
    ...
    def data_json():
        data = []
        ...
        return data
```

But it doesn't seems to work.
I don't know how to bite it.

I tried to understand how class-based-views work, what is derived from what and which function is calling `get` etc. but the manual doesn't explain this.

**I really want to do this in one class**

Comment: `class Index(jsonMixin, MyViewBase)` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put the mixin before MyViewBase, because the Python method lookup.

```
class Index(jsonMixin, MyViewBase):
    ...
    def data_json():
        data = []
        ...
        return data
```

hope helps